# Embedding pdf file in HTML page

Tags: html, css, pdf, browser

How do i embed a pdf file into a HTML document without scrollbars..?

I need to display the whole pages of pdf file in the HTML document.

if the pdf file have 10 pages then the i need to display the whole 10 pages in the HTML document without the scrollbars.

I have tried this code but not worked properly.

```
<iframe src="/Path to my pdf file#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=1&zoom=133" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

[Result of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf4TP.jpg)

i got this result but i want to remove the scrollbar and display the full pad in my page.

please help..........

Comment: you can't get iframes height base on content, because the parent HTML DOM can't reach Child HTML DOM content. HTML DOMs are isolated (for a good reason). You have to manually set iframes height. If you know the whole document aspect ratio, you can recalculate it's height with javascript on resize listener.+

Comment: Is there a better way to do this without using iFrames?